# Add a link to a label/hint in formtastic with haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, formtastic

I'm trying to add a link to a checkbox in formtastic, using haml. It looks like formtastic removes all ruby/haml/html syntax from the text for the label or hint when it parses it.

That is, this doesn't work:

```
= f.input :terms, label: '=link_to \'Here\', path_to_link', hint: '=link_to \'Other Place\', path_to_other_link', as: :boolean
```

Is there anything that will other than writing another div outside of this input? Or am I going about this all wrong? I'm a rails/haml/formtastic noob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you use ' for string quotation, you're basically telling ruby not to parse that content.

try something like this instead:

```
= f.input :terms, label: link_to('Here', path_to_link), hint: link_to('Other place', path_to_other_link), as: :boolean
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Formtastic::FormBuilder.escape_html_entities_in_hints_and_labels = false
```

In your formtastic initializer

Comment: This is the best answer for using I18n localization files that contain static HTML content. However, it does not resolve @tessr question of embedding HAML in a Formtastic label or hint.

Answer (score 1):

If you mark the string passed to `label:` or `hint:` as HTML safe then Haml doesn't escape it.

```
= f.input :terms,
  label: "Please accept our ".html_safe + link_to('Terms and Conditions', path_to_link)
```

Answer (score 0):

19 ways tried, with either the hyperlink being encoded or html_safe replacing hyphens in the url ???

This is what worked for me

```
<%= f.label :cookies do
  "Do you agree to our #{link_to('Cookies Policy', 'http://www.your-­url.co.uk/privacypolicy')}".html_safe
end %>
```

The specific use of " and ' appears significant.